# Find Fb Post id from url with regex

Tags: php, regex, facebook

I am having an issue with regex. Can someone help me to capture the last URL's id?

Regex:
 
`(?:(?:http|https):\/\/(?:www|m|mbasic|business)\.(?:facebook|fb)\.com\/)(?:photo(?:\.php|s)|permalink\.php|video\.php|media|watch\/|questions|notes|[^\/]+\/(?:activity|posts|videos|photos))[\/?](?:fbid=|story_fbid=|id=|b=|v=|)([0-9]+|[^\/]+\/[\d]+)`

Regex Link: https://regex101.com/r/TvJ7Uh/15

URLs:

```
https://m.facebook.com/pagefdgname/posts/990086801384551/ ✔️ Works
https://mbasic.facebook.com/username/posts/990086801384551:b ✔️ Works
https://www.facebook.com/username/activity/990086801384551rt ✔️ Works
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=990086801384551=?=works ✔️ Works
https://mbasic.facebook.com/photos/990086801384551 ✔️ Works
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=990086801384551&? ✔️ Works
https://www.facebook.com/questions/990086801384551/ ✔️ Works
https://www.facebook.com/page-name/videos/990086801384551/ ✔️ Works
https://www.facebook.com/username/videos/990086801384551/ ✔️ Works
http://business.facebook.com/watch/?v=990086801384551 ✔️ Works
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?id=990086801384551 ✔️ Works
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=990086801384551 ✔️ Works
https://www.facebook.com/sgsxdfg/photos/pb.104-958162837./990086801384551/ ❌ Issue
```

I want to capture `990086801384551` from Last URL

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html), replace the last `([0-9]+|[^\/]+\/[\d]+)` with `(?|([0-9]+)|[^\/]+\/(\d+))`.

The updated regex will look like

```
(?:https?:\/\/(?:www|m|mbasic|business)\.(?:facebook|fb)\.com\/)(?:photo(?:\.php|s)|permalink\.php|video\.php|media|watch\/|questions|notes|[^\/]+\/(?:activity|posts|videos|photos))[\/?](?:fbid=|story_fbid=|id=|b=|v=|)(?|([0-9]+)|[^\/]+\/(\d+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TvJ7Uh/17)

Note that `(?:http|https)` has been contracted to `https?`.